# Как сделать эффект размытия в android?

Tags: java, android

уважаемые знатоки. Столкнулся с проблемой создания эффекта размытия.

Есть активность:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/group_807"
    android:layout_width="264dp"
    android:layout_height="374.77dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="327.23dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="66dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/ellipse_265"
    android:layout_width="160.7dp"
    android:layout_height="160.7dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="214.7dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="103.3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ellipse_265"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/group_807"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/group_807"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/group_807"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/group_807" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/ellipse_262"
    android:layout_width="114.78dp"
    android:layout_height="114.78dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="121.67dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="149.22dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="138.31dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ellipse_262"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/group_807"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/group_807"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/group_807"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/group_807" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/ellipse_264"
    android:layout_width="160.7dp"
    android:layout_height="160.7dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="88.96dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="14.35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="214.07dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ellipse_264"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/group_807"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/group_807"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/group_807"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/group_807" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/ellipse_263"
    android:layout_width="114.78dp"
    android:layout_height="114.78dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="56.69dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="149.22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200.3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ellipse_263"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/group_807"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/group_807"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/group_807"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/group_807" />
```

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно наложить блюр, что-то вроде этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно реализовать данную задачу? Возможно с помощью какой-то библиотеки? радиус блюра должен быть 100px

Comment: Вот список библиотек: https://medium.com/mindorks/android-top-blur-effects-libraries-f53b0201203c

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641973/how-to-blur-background-images-in-android